# How to use a string in an if statement with properties Settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am currently working in winforms c#. I have a **string** "Flippo1SN" and that **string** is determined in my form. "Flippo1SN" can change in *'serial number names'* that matches the same *name* as in **Properties.Settings** . The value of the serial numbers in **Properties.Settings** are **integers**. I want to use an **if statement** without summing up all the **integers** in my **Properties.Settings**, instead, I want to use a **string** so I could write my code in 1 **if statement** instead of more. I tried to use a code like this:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Flippo1SN == 0) {}
```

Which, as you may have guessed, did not work. I've tried more ways as:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.(Flippo1SN) == 0) {}
if (Properties.Settings.Default.("Flippo1SN") == 0) {}
if (Properties.Settings.Default.[Flippo1SN] == 0) {}
if (Properties.Settings.Default.["Flippo1SN"] == 0) {}
```

It gives me an error saying that there is an indentifier expected.
How can I solve this? This question may have already been asked in the past but I couldn't find it.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

**Flippo1SN** Does not exist in Properties.Settings, it is its value that does. Its value is something like: GF01, GF02, ... I am trying to refer to those.

**Edit 2:**

[image]

These are the variables I am trying to refer to. **Flippo1SN**s name changes to *GF01* or *GF02* etc. I don't want to put a code like this:

```
if (Flippo1SN == "GF01")
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.GF01 == 0) {//Do action}
}
```

Instead, I want to refer to *GF01* immediately by using **Flippo1SN** in the second if statement. That would cost me a lot of time and writing because I have a lot of **Integers** in **Properties.Settings** .
**Edit 3**

I'm going to explain what I am creating so you guys understand what I'm doing.

I am creating a 'Collecting Game' where you collect Flippos (Pogs or milk caps is what it's called in English I guess?). To get those Flippos, you open a giftbox and receive 3 random flippos. The output is something like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT7Sr.png) ("Verzamel" means collect)
In this image, you see 3 flippos. In the top left corner, you see the Serial Numbers of each flippo (MF06, GF16, OF12). 'MF' stands for 'Mega Flippo', 'GF' for Green Flippo and 'OF' stands for 'Orange Flippo'.

In the code, I have used random to choose which one you get (50% chance for green, 30% chance for orange and 20% chance for mega. The percentage is determined by the amount of a specific group). I have also 3 strings in my code that holds the serial number of these flippos (Flippo1SN, Flippo2SN, and Flippo3SN). These serial numbers refer to the ones in my database (or just the properties.settings tab). In this scenario, MF06, GF16 and OF12 increments by 1.

Now, I want to check if you've received a flippo you didn't have before. If you do so, a label will appear above the picture and the text of that label will be "New".

To do so, I first need to check which one you have received, then check if you already have that in your database. The first if checks if you have received GF01 and the second if checks if you already have it:

```
if (Flippo1SN == "GF01")
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.GF01 == 0)
    {
        label1.Show();
    }
}
else if (FLippo1SN == "GF02") {//ETC}
```

Flippo1SN is already determined. I am not trying to change the Flippo1SNs value. I am just using this string to check which flippo you have received. All flippos have a serial number and Flippo1SN holds a serial number to refer to which flippo you have received.

What I now am asking is, is there a more fast way to do this? Can't I use the value of Flippo1SN immediately in an if statement so I could avoid multiple if statements?

I really hope I made things clear now.

Comment: if (Properties.Settings.Default["Flippo1SN"] == 0) ... Although, if (Properties.Settings.Default.Flippo1SN == 0) should've worked.  I do something similar below.

Comment: Maybe show your settings dialog so we can get a clue what you are talking about.  It's very unclear what's going on here.

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default[Flippo1SN]`

Comment: Also, just realized you said Flippo1SN was a string.  Strings are literals.  So, you'd need to say  == "0"  or   == NULL .... Unless, you're checking the length of the string.  That's a int.

Comment: Imagine 'Flippo1SN' = "GF01", I want to refer to GF01 in properties.Settings by writing 'Properties.Settings.Default.[Flippo1SN]'

Comment: Notice @RezaAghaei comment.  The "dot" is not used after the word "Default", where in your code, you always have a "dot".

Comment: Does the first if need to check flippo1SN against the value of GF01?  if it does .. if ((Flippo1SN == Properties.Settings.Default.GF01).  If you want to stop typing Properties.Settings.Default, add a global variable like [ dynamic props = Properties.Settings.Default ]  Now, you can just say, props.GF01, props.GF02, etc ...

Comment: Sorry, Flippo1SN is a string you said, I forgot again.  You'd have to add .ToString() to the end of GF01, etc ...Properties.Settings.Default.GF01.ToString()

Comment: @tobeypeters Instead of typing GF01 and GF02 etc over and over again, I want to refer to them by using a string.

Comment: Ok .. So Flippo1SN is a string variable and it "points" to one of the GFxx values?   Now you want to ask does Flippo1SN equal the the value of GF01 ... do this .. ELSE does it equal GF02 ... do this ... ?  The, if (Flippo1SN == Properties.Settings.Default.GF01.ToString()) {} or use the short method I mentioned ... dynamic props = Properties.Settings.Default;   if (Flippo1SN == props.GF01.ToString()) {} ... DId I finally understand what you want?  Yes, then I'd use a switch statement, to keep from a million if statements.

Comment: @tobeypeters that is correct.

Comment: @Emre the plain solution is Properties.Settings.Default[Flippo1SN] as mentioned already.

Comment: My last comment was edited earlier.  Forget the part, about using a switch.  You can't, in this case.

Comment: @tobeypeters I have explained what I am doing in my program so you can this time understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: It's unclear why you keep ignoring the solution that's been given to you already.

Comment: From your last edit, I believe ozum.e posted the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check if it exists then you can do whatever you want with it:

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default.ContainsKey(Flippo1SN))
{
    if(Properties.Settings.Default[Flippo1SN] == 0)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

You can also write handlers to get rid of the if checks:

```
interface ISettingsHandler
{
    void Handle(int value);
    bool CanHandle(string name);
} 

class GF1Handler : ISettingsHandler
{
    public void Handle(int value){
        // do action
    }

    public bool CanHandle(string propertyName){
        return propertyName.Equals("GF1");
    }
} 

class GF2Handler : ISettingsHandler
{
    public void Handle(int value){
        // do action
    }

    public bool CanHandle(string propertyName){
        return propertyName.Equals("GF2");
    }
}
```

You can then initialize a list of handlers, and use the one that can handle the selected property:

```
var handler = listOfHandler.FirstOrDefault(h => h.CanHandle(Flippo1SN))
if( != null)
    handler.Handle(Properties.Settings.Default[Flippo1SN]);
```

Comment: 'ContainsKey' is not even possible for me to use. Check my edit to get a better understanding of what I try to mean.

Comment: Hi Emre, you can check my edit to see how you can check the value directly.

Comment: if(Properties.Settings.Default[Flippo1SN] == 0)

Comment: Interesting ... I like what you did here.

Comment: I am someone who uses simple code because I am a hobbyist and am not really that good at it. You give me a solution with handlers, but I have never used a handler in my life and I don't even understand it. I think I should first read some "What are handlers", "How to use handlers" so I could understand your solution better.

Comment: @Emre i understand, i just want to help you emre. You can start reading about c# design patterns, you will get better and better in time with practise.

Answer (score 1):

By using `Properties.Settings.Default` you can retrieve all the properties in your `Project`.

Then, by iterating through them you can check the `Name` of each property to see if it matches your `Flippo1SN` like so:

```
string Flippo1SN = "GF02";
var props = Properties.Settings.Default;

foreach(var prop in props.Properties)
{
    var settingProperty = (SettingsProperty)prop;

    if (settingProperty.Name == Flippo1SN)
    {
        // Now you found the property that matches Flippo1SN.
        // Get its value.
        var value = settingProperty.DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

### Edit:

How to check if value of the property is zero:

```
string Flippo1SN = "GF02";
foreach (SettingsProperty prop in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    if (prop.Name == Flippo1SN)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(prop.DefaultValue.ToString(), out int result))
        {
            if (result == 0)
            {
                // The value is zero.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does work however, how could I now check if the value of that properties.settings is equal to zero?

Comment: That's already in the answer. The variable `value` contains the value of that property in `string` format. Do an `int.TryParse()` to convert it into an `int` and do an integer comparison.

Comment: It executes the code even though the value isn't zero.

Comment: It goes into the inner-most `if` statement ONLY if the value of `result` equals zero. You should double check.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: NEW CODE AND SCREENSHOTS**

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        dynamic props = Properties.Settings.Default;
        string Flippo1SN = "200";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output = "Properties.Settings.Default.test : ";

            if (Flippo1SN == props.test.ToString())
            {
                output += $"{props.test}";
            }
            if (Flippo1SN == props.test2.ToString())
            {
                output += $"{props.test2}";
            }
            if (Flippo1SN == props.test3.ToString())
            {
                output += $"{props.test3}";
            }

            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Flippo1SN does not exist in properties.settings, it's its value that does exist. Like (GF01, GF02, GF03, ...). I am trying to refer to those.

Comment: So, do you need to check the existence, of GF01, etc .. and set this string to a given value?  I'm confused.  Then, you need to do what ozum.e said and do ContainsKey().

Comment: I have updated my question once again and added a picture this time. Hope I made it clear this time.